# T(n)=T(n-2)+T(n-3)+T(n-4)+2 is O(log n)?

Tags: data-structures, recursion

how can i prove that T(n)=T(n-2)+T(n-3)+T(n-4)+2  is O(logn)? 
or T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-3)+1 the same..
when T(0)=1 T(1)=2 T(2)=3 T(3)=5 T(4)=8 etc`..

it's a Q about AVL-2 tree,the same rules of AVL tree who rotate after 3 levels diff between L,R childs.. and not 2 as AVL tree

thanks for all.

Comment: For both, look, for example, at the first ten values. There's no way these grow as slowly as $\log n$. Even if, say, we replaced the first by just  $T(n)=T(n-2)+2$ we'd have $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Are you sure that solves to $O(\log n)$? That doesn't sound right. You might want to look at the annihilator method for solving linear recurrences; it probably will work here.

Comment: well.. thank for all...
the ans is T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-3)+1<=T(n)=T(n-3)+T(n-3)+1

Comment: well.. thank for all...
the ans is 
T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-3)+1≤T(n)=T(n-3)+T(n-3)+1
T(n)=T(n-3)+T(n-3)+1=T(n)=2*T(n-3)+1
T(n-3)=2*T(n-6)+1=> T(n)=2*[2T(n-6)+1]+1
T(n-6)=2*T(n-9)+1=>T(n)=2*2*[2T(n-9)+1]+1+1
.....
T(o)=2*(2*(2*(2*(...*2*(2*1+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)...+1)
T(0)≤2^(n/3).. :?